# How to remove header "ish" label

Tags: themes

I've been trying to remove this for an extented period of time, and it seems to be easy to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my awnser, few minutes after, this part is called breadcrumps, there is always a place somewhere that I can disable it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so this question does not turn up as "unanswered" later.

Comment: I only can in 2 days